# send email function and arguments - Zend error "Subject set twice"

Tags: php, zend-framework, foreach

I know it doesn't work but how can i fit $salesData and $salesData2 into the send email function?

```
$salesData['email']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email');
$salesData['name']   = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/name');
$salesData2['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email');
$salesData2['name']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/name');
```

Is there a way to do something like so?

```
$emailTemplate->send($salesData && $salesData2, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Seems so simple but my brain isn't working today. The above does not work.

I've also tried a foreach like so:

```
$emails = (Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email')) && (Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email'));

foreach ($emails as $email) $emailTemplate->send($email, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

---

Full method:

```
private function _sendStatusMail($product)
    {
        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
        $emailTemplate->loadDefault('elic_productnotification_tpl');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Product has been disabled');

        $salesData['email']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email');
        $salesData['name']   = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/name');
        $salesData2['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email');
        $salesData2['name']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData2['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData2['email']);

        $emailTemplateVariables['style_number']   = $product->getElicStyle();
        $emailTemplateVariables['frame_color']    = $product->getAttributeText('frame_color');
        $emailTemplateVariables['size']           = $product->getAttributeText('size');
        $emailTemplateVariables['elic_color'] = $product->getAttributeText('elic_color');
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name']     = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($product->getStoreId())->getName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['product_name']   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['product_sku']    = $product->getSku();
        $emailTemplateVariables['dates']          = date("F jS Y h:i:sA", strtotime('-7 hours'));

        $email = (Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email'));
        foreach ($emails as $email) $emailTemplate->send($email, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge two arrays with a [logical AND](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) `&&`.

Instead, use two loops instead:

```
$emailsA = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email');
$emailsB = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email');

foreach ($emailsA as $email) $emailTemplate->send($email, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
foreach ($emailsB as $email) $emailTemplate->send($email, $product->getStoreId(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Extract duplicate code into functions at your discretion.

Comment: Really? This might be what i'm looking for and I should of known that... it seems logical. Let me test it real quick.

Comment: I got an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help.

```
function mail_walk($name,$body,$subject,$email) {
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$emailTemplate->setFromName($name);
$emailTemplate->setBody($body);
$emailTemplate->setSubject($subject);
$emailTemplate->setType('html');
$emailTemplate->setToEmail($email);
$emailTemplate->send();
}

$salesData[0]['name']   = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/name');
$salesData[0]['email']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom3/email');
$salesData[1]['name']   = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/name');
$salesData[1]['email']  = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom4/email');

foreach ($salesData as $data) {
mail_walk($data['name'],'email body here...','Subject in here...',$data['email']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me have a look at what you did here.  =]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I already have a Private function which i want to keep. The problem is on the backend/admin... the email addresses are throwing and error because of the explode. Zend is saying "Subject set twice" and it doesn't fire.

Comment: I posted the full function above. So i'm trying to minimize the rework at this point.

Comment: `$body` is `$emailTemplateVariables` for you... @thismethod